# Number theory, prime

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ and $s$ be two different odd prime. $x,y$ are two integers relatively prime.

If $p$ divides $(x^s+y^s)/(x+y)$, show that $p\equiv 1 \pmod s.$

First, I let $y=-t.$ So we get $p$ divides $(x^s-t^s)/(x-t)= \sum_{i=0}^{s-1} x^it^{s-1-i} $.
I tried mod $s$ but then I find that I lost the part where $p$ devides it in integers. I can only get $np=1 (mod s)$  for some n. But it is trivial.

Then I tried mod $p.$ But it looks like not helpful.

Can any one give some hint about it. I guess I need to do mod $s^2,s^3$ but I have a hard time to find a way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with that. @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Use your expansion
   $$\frac{x^l-t^l}{x-t} = \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} x^it^{l-1-i}$$
   to show that $p$ divides neither $x$, nor $t$ (or equivalently, $y$). The fact that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime will be helpful.
2. What happens if $x \equiv t \pmod{p}$? Recall that $l \neq p$.
3. Otherwise, consider the expression $\frac{x^l-t^l}{x-t}$ in the field $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Apply Fermat's Little Theorem (or Euler's Theorem).

Comment: If $x \neq t (mod p)$ then it means $x^l=t^l (mod p)$. So, $(x/t)^l=1 (mod p) $. Thus, say $char(x/t) = n$, we get $gcd(l,p-1)=n$ but l is prime. So n = 1 or l. If $n = l$, it means $x=t mod p$ but we assume it is not. So, $n=l$ which implies l divides p-1. Then we get $p=1 (mod l)$

Answer (score 0):

If $x=t (mod p)$, let $x= t +np$. So we can simplify $(x^s-t^s)/(x-t)= s*t^{s-1} mod p$. But t is invertible in $Z/pZ$. So we get $s=0 mod p $ which is impossible.
Thus , $x-t$ is invertible in $Z/pZ$, which means $x^s=t^s (modp)$.
So,$(x/t)^s = 1 (mod p)$. By fermat little theorem, we get $char(x/t)|gcd(p-1,s) $.
So, $char(x/t) = 1 or s$. But we already know $x/t \neq 1 (mod p)$. So, the only choice is s.
That means s divides p-1, which means $p=1 (mod s)$

Comment: You have the right idea, but there are a few issues. First, $p \mid \frac{x^s - t^s}{x - t} \; \to \; p \mid x^s - t^s \; \to \; x^s \equiv t^s \pmod{p}$. Thus, you don't require that $x - t$ is invertible to get $x^s \equiv t^s \pmod{p}$. Instead, the issue with invertibility is that $t$ is invertible (instead of just stating this as you did, you may wish to prove this by showing that if $p \mid t$, then $p \mid x$ which is not allowed as $x$ and $t$ must be coprime). This is so you can get $(xt^{-1})^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. I hope you find this of some assistance.

Comment: Here's also a few MathJax formatting tips. Instead of  `x=t (mod p)` showing as $x=t (mod p)$, I suggest `x \equiv t \pmod{p}` which shows as $x \equiv t \pmod{p}$. For "divides", instead of using `|` which appears like $a|b$, you should use `\mid` to get $a \mid b$ (also, for "doesn't divide", note `not|` appears like $a\not|b$, but `\not\mid` or `\nmid` shows like $a \nmid b$). For "gcd", instead of $gcd$, using `\gcd` gives $\gcd$. Other unrecognized operators like your "char" giving you $char$, use `\operatorname{char}` instead to get $\operatorname{char}$.